# Cannot read phone contacts in android

Tags: android

I use this code for reading ohone contact.

```
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); 
         if(cursor.moveToFirst()&&cursor.getCount()>0&&cursor!=null){

               // String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID)); 
                String name      = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phone     =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

}
```

But these `"ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME" ,"ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER"` return -1 that causes exception.

How should I sove this prblem?

Comment: use DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor to see all the columns you can use,  phone number is not among them

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext())
{
  String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
  String phone = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

}
phones.close();
```